# Why won't text-transform work on SVG text in Firefox?

Tags: html, css, svg

I started experimenting with SVG and I'm not sure if this is something I'm doing wrong, it's not supported or it's just a Firefox bug.

This is the line in SVG

```
<text x="177" y="658">Web Interactive</text>
```

These are the styles

```
svg text{
position:relative;
font-size:7.3em;
font-family:'GothamBookRegular',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-variant:normal;
font-style:normal;
text-transform:uppercase;
text-align:left;
fill:#282828;
color:#282828;
}
```

This works in Opera, Chrome, IE9 and Safari. I've also tested `letter-spacing`, and it works on all but Firefox too.

Reference page: [SVG Experimenting](http://heyvian.com/svg/indexb.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't work in all browsers because it is not a valid SVG property. It doesn't appear in this list:

http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/propidx.html

There were questions about it on Bugzilla, but the conclusion was not to add it to Firefox.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=682124

Comment: A workaround for `text-transform:uppercase`? Yes, certainly. But are you sure you want to hear this? You won't like it...

Comment: :) Not just the uppercase and that actually doesn't work because it changes the letter-spacing, which then again can't be corrected because letter-spacing is not a property in SVG either. :P I did set myself up for that but what I meant was a workaround for "advanced" formatting of text in SVG. Placing HTML text below the SVG doesn't work either because it doesn't scale the same.

Comment: Actually, text-spacing is a property but it definitely doesn't work either.

Comment: I don't know, sorry, I'm not an SVG guru; only started diving into it a couple of months back and struck the same obstacles as you did. For instance that the result doesn't look the same in different browsers. Haven't found any solutions.

Answer (score 7):

You can't use css, but you can always capitalize with javascript. If you want all svg text elements to be capitalized. In my case, it had tspan elements inside text elements, so this was my (jquery) code:

```
$('svg text tspan').each( function (){
    txt = $(this).text().toUpperCase();
    $(this).text(txt);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no text-transform property in SVG: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/propidx.html If it works in other browsers then it's probably because it's just because the html text and SVG text rendering shares code. Any browser might remove this feature I guess since its not in the specification, although it's more likely that it will be added to a future version of the SVG specfication than removed from existing implementations. letter-spacing is just not yet implemented in Firefox though: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=371787